# Invalid JSON response: Bootstrap datatables

Tags: jquery, json, codeigniter, datatable, datatables

I have here a datatables connect with database using codeigniter. The problem here was my datatables wasn't display the output. I check in developer tools/ network if the data through ajax is sent to my controller and it was. Any help will appreciate.

My Controller

```
    class Person extends MY_Controller {

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model('person_model','person');
    }

    public function index()
    {
        $this->load->helper('url');
        $this->data['title'] = 'Division'; 
        $this->middle = 'person_view'; // its your view name, change for as per requirement.
        $this->layout();
    }

    public function ajax_list()
    {
        $list = $this->person->get_datatables();
        $data = array();
        $no = $_POST['start'];
        foreach ($list as $division) {
            $no++;
            $row = array();
            $row[] = $division->division_code;
            $row[] = $division->division_name;
            $row[] = $division->division_acro;

            //add html for action
            $row[] = '<a class="btn btn-sm btn-primary" href="javascript:void(0)" title="Edit" onclick="edit_person('."'".$division->id."'".')"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></i> Edit</a>
                  <a class="btn btn-sm btn-danger" href="javascript:void(0)" title="Hapus" onclick="delete_person('."'".$division->id."'".')"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></i> Delete</a>';

            $data[] = $row;
        }

        $output = array(
                        "draw" => $_POST['draw'],
                        "recordsTotal" => $this->person->count_all(),
                        "recordsFiltered" => $this->person->count_filtered(),
                        "data" => $data,
                );
        //output to json format
        echo json_encode($output);
    }
}
```

My Model

```
class Person_model extends CI_Model {

    var $table = 'division';
    var $column_order = array('division_code','division_name','division_acro','division_date',null); //set column field database for datatable orderable
    var $column_search = array('division_code','division_name','division_acro'); //set column field database for datatable searchable just firstname , lastname , address are searchable
    var $order = array('id' => 'desc'); // default order 

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->database();
    }

    private function _get_datatables_query()
    {

        $this->db->from($this->table);

        $i = 0;

        foreach ($this->column_search as $item) // loop column 
        {
            if($_POST['search']['value']) // if datatable send POST for search
            {

                if($i===0) // first loop
                {
                    $this->db->group_start(); // open bracket. query Where with OR clause better with bracket. because maybe can combine with other WHERE with AND.
                    $this->db->like($item, $_POST['search']['value']);
                }
                else
                {
                    $this->db->or_like($item, $_POST['search']['value']);
                }

                if(count($this->column_search) - 1 == $i) //last loop
                    $this->db->group_end(); //close bracket
            }
            $i++;
        }

        if(isset($_POST['order'])) // here order processing
        {
            $this->db->order_by($this->column_order[$_POST['order']['0']['column']], $_POST['order']['0']['dir']);
        } 
        else if(isset($this->order))
        {
            $order = $this->order;
            $this->db->order_by(key($order), $order[key($order)]);
        }
    }

    function get_datatables()
    {
        $this->_get_datatables_query();
        if($_POST['length'] != -1)
        $this->db->limit($_POST['length'], $_POST['start']);
        $query = $this->db->get();
        return $query->result();
    }

    function count_filtered()
    {
        $this->_get_datatables_query();
        $query = $this->db->get();
        return $query->num_rows();
    }

    public function count_all()
    {
        $this->db->from($this->table);
        return $this->db->count_all_results();
    }
```

My view script

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var save_method; //for save method string
var table;

$(document).ready(function() {

    //datatables
    table = $('#table').DataTable({ 

        "processing": true, //Feature control the processing indicator.
        "serverSide": true, //Feature control DataTables' server-side processing mode.
        "order": [], //Initial no order.

        // Load data for the table's content from an Ajax source
        "ajax": {
            "url": "<?php echo  ('person/ajax_list')?>",
            "type": "POST"
        },

        //Set column definition initialisation properties.
        "columnDefs": [
        { 
            "targets": [ -1 ], //last column
            "orderable": false, //set not orderable
        },
        ],

    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: what's response you are getting in your ajax call ?

Comment: Look at the response in the Network tab of Developer Tools. The controller is probably printing something before or after the JSON, you need to fix that.

Comment: @RajJagani I get the data in my database just like this. - "draw":"1","recordsTotal":43,"recordsFiltered":43,"data":[["div-043","Division","D"," and so on.

Comment: @Barmar just want to ask. I'm using codeigniter my_controller. I have my asset for layout. If is one of the problem that triggers the error? What should I change in my router or autoload or so on.

Comment: which datatable version you are using ? I have a complete code for **Datatable version 1.10.9**. if you are using 1.X.X than I can put that code.

Comment: @RajJagani  this what i've been used. DataTables integration for Bootstrap 3. This requires Bootstrap 3 and * DataTables 1.10 or newer.

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code

**In controller**

```
public function datatable()
    {
        if($this->input->is_ajax_request()) {
            $start = $this->input->post('iDisplayStart');
            $limit = $this->input->post('iDisplayLength');
            $data['employee'] = $this->admin_details_model->get_all_admin($limit, $start); //your model function from where you can get the data.
            $total_records = $filtered_records = $this->admin_details_model->total_admin_records(); //model functions to get total records
            $output = array(
                "sEcho"                => intval($this->input->post('sEcho')),
                "iTotalRecords"        => $total_records,
                "iTotalDisplayRecords" => $filtered_records,
                "aaData" => array()
            );
            foreach($data['employee'] as $post) {
                $action = '<a title="Edit" href="'.site_url("admin/edit/".md5($post->id)).'"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-edit"></i></a> <a title="Delete" class="delete-global" datatable-var="admin_table" href="'.site_url("admin/delete/".md5($post->id)).'"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-trash"></i></a>';
                $aaData   = array();
                $aaData[] = $post->first_name.' '.$post->last_name;
                //$aaData[] = $post->last_name;
                $aaData[] = $post->email;
                $aaData[] = $post->phone;
                $aaData[] = $post->status;
                $aaData[] = $action;
                $output['aaData'][] = $aaData;
            }
            echo json_encode($output);
        } else {
            redirect('login'); // redirect to your default page if any one try to access directly.
        }
    }
```

**In your JS**

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    if($('#admin_list').length > 0){
        var emp_table = $('#admin_list').dataTable({
            "aoColumns": [
              { "bSortable": false },
              { "bSortable": false },
              { "bSortable": false },
              { "bSortable": false },
              { "bSortable": false },
            ],
            'bProcessing'   : true,
            "bServerSide": true,
            "sAjaxSource": 'http://localhost/admin/admin/datatable', //put your ajax source url
            "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
            "sDom": "t<'row'<'col-sm-6'i><'col-sm-6'p>>", // put your SDOM as this is little bit different as I have hide the header options of datatables
            "fnServerData": function (sSource, aoData, fnCallback)
            {
                $.ajax
                        ({
                            'dataType': 'json',
                            'type': 'POST',
                            'url': sSource,
                            'data': aoData,
                            'success': fnCallback
                        });
            },
             "oLanguage": {
                "sLengthMenu": "_MENU_ records per page",
                "sZeroRecords": "No data available",
            },
        });
    }
});
```

**In the view**

```
<div class="col-lg-12">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                <h3 class="panel-title"><?php echo 'admin_list'; ?></h3>
            </div>
            <div class="panel-body">
                <div class="table-responsive dt-custom">
                    <table id="admin_list" class="table table-bordered table-hover table-striped">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th><?php echo lang('full_name'); ?></th>
        <!--                        <th><?php //echo lang('last_name'); ?></th>-->
                                <th><?php echo 'email'; ?></th>
                                <th><?php echo 'phone'; ?></th>
                                <th><?php echo 'status'; ?></th>
                                <th><?php echo 'action'; ?></th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>

                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>    
    </div>
```

Please follow the comments I have mentioned along with code and also **set datatables options** as per your requirement. Hope this will work for you.

Comment: Okay I will try it.

Answer (score 0):

If the server didn't reply to the Ajax request with valid JSON data, we need to know what it did reply with, so we can take corrective action. Typically, the response will consist of an error message from the program on the server which is being used to create the JSON, which will be the starting point for resolving the issue fully.

//I'm using google chrome
1. Hit Ctrl+Shift+I to open developer tools
2. Go to network tab
3. View the ajax response...(Mybe it was an error in your data...
4. Correct any errors